What options to have to present a list of actions, after using 先ず for the first one?
e.g. First you (a). Then, you (b). After that, you (c), etc. I remember seeing something about it years ago, but have never been able to find anything close to it, ever since

First action
The following terms are commonly used to indicate the first action:

まず
最初に
始めに
はじめに

You can write まず in Kanji as 先ず, but hiragana form まず is much more common.
2nd or later actions
The following terms are commonly used to indicate subsequent actions:

次に next
そして and then
さらに furthermore
その後で after that

Final action
The following terms are commonly used to indicate the last action. Note that 仕上げに is used specifically in contexts such as cooking, creating or cleaning something.

最後に lastly
仕上げに, in the final step (typically in cooking or production)

Examples:
最初にお湯を入れます。そして3分間待ちます。最後にタレをかければカップ麺の完成です。
First, pour hot water into it. Then wait for 3 minutes. Lastly, add the sauce, and the instant noodle is ready.
Since this example is about how to cook instant noodle, you can replace 最後に with 仕上げに:
最初にお湯を入れます。そして3分間待ちます。 仕上げにタレをかければカップ麺の完成です。
Here is another example
最初に赤いボタンを押し、次に緑のボタン、最後に青いボタンを押します。
First, press the red button, then the green button, lastly press the blue button.
In this example, since it involves simply pressing  buttons and not creating something, so you cannot replace 最後に with 仕上げに unless pressing the buttons results in building or cleaning something.
